# limiting access to pnp4nagios graphs, for example using nagios contacts

Tags: nagios

I have nagios contacts set up, and these successfully limit access to view hosts and services in the nagios web UI.

But pnp4nagios gives access to all graphs (by editing the hostname and service name in the URL) - it does not respect the nagios-defined access controls.

Is it possible to configure this? (either using nagios contacts, or some other ACL mechanism)

Answer (score 0):

It is the Nagios cgi code that limits access to specific 'pages' of the GUI.  So this solution would depend on the whether you wanted to restrict access to all graphs - this would require you to copy over the ACL entry used in your httpd server to the folder used for the pnp4nagios code and temp file directories.  If, however, you wanted to duplicate the rights used by Nagios - you would have to modify the pnp4nagios code to perform what the Nagios cgi code does.  I'd submit a request to pnp4nagios.org, they may do this for you.